# Copy On-Prem Flat file to Azure Blob using Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load a **Flat file** to **BLOB** using the **ADF V2**. I have installed the Self Hosted Integration Runtime for the same. The Integration Runtime on Local Machine shows that is successfully connected to the cloud Service as in the SC below.  However while making the LinkedService to the on Prem File, some credentials are required. I am not sure of what **UserName** or **Password** should be fed in. I have tried both On-Prem and Azure passwords (Wanted to try). Please see the SC.

Could you please guide as how the connection can be made to a local Flat file in my case.

Thanks 
- Akshay
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LinkedService connection to BLOB or AzureSQL Server are being blocked by the firewall of my organisation. It won't let my system Integration runtime connect my resources to the public cloud.
I followed the same steps on my personal machine and everything went smoothly. Will get the firewall restrictions sorted and update this link for more information.

Comment: Hey Akshay, Glad to know that your issue has resolved. Could you share the detailed steps which you tried to fix this issue, which might be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: The steps remain the same as mentioned in following MSDN Link. Your post also has the same steps in a condensed way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/data-factory/tutorial-hybrid-copy-data-tool

Comment: I would tomorrow as Stack says "You can mark your own answer tomorrow" !

Comment: No worries. Make sure to do it tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** You can choose a file while creating the File System as a source in ADF.

You may follow the following steps to select the text file while creating File system as source:

First create a linked service as follows:

Host: `**C:\AzureLearn\**`

[image]

Create a copy activity and select Source as follows:

Click on Source => New

[image]

Select New DataSet => Select File => File System and continue

[image]

Select Format= > Choose DelimitedText and continue

[image]

=> Select previously created File system linked service and click on browse.

[image]

Choose a file or folder.

Here you can find the file located under the previously selected folder while creating File System.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for sharing your answer. I think my query wasn't clear enough for which I regret. I wasn't able to make a successful LinkedService Connection due to User ID and Password. "The Set properties" pane comes only when your Connection is successful,which wasn't in my case.

Comment: If you are on domain you should use username as user@organization.com and password should works.